# Getting Kinect Serial on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, usb, kinect, lsusb

I connected a new Kinect (XBOX 360) to my Ubuntu 12.04 Machine. Using `lsusb` I tried to find the serial number of the Kinect device. But I get the following output:

```
iManufacturer           2 Microsoft
iProduct                1 Xbox NUI Camera
iSerial                 3 0000000000000000
```

Any ideas whats going wrong here?

Comment: What are you going to do with this serial number?

Comment: I'm using multiple kinects and I want to identify deivces by serial. E.g I want to store calibration files using serials as names. This is the only device where I cant read the serial.

Comment: I would download the source to lsusb and verify the code even attempts to get the serial number.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have [reported problems connecting to the Kinect using 12.04](http://answers.ros.org/question/9179/kinect-and-usb-30/).  It may be worth upgrading your distro or Kernel.

If you're running `lsusb -v` as `sudo` then you *should* be seeing a serial number.  If not, what happens if you try using a wrapper like [freenect](http://wiki.ros.org/freenect_stack)?

Comment: Actually I have no problems connecting the kinect - the camera is working well. It's just the serial: Always `0000000000000000`. Even if I run `lsusb -v` as `sudo`...

Comment: Sadly, this appears to be by design - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7118c11-3577-4981-a5f3-62a7cc8ac599/kinect-for-windows-uniquekinectid-is-always-0000000000000000?forum=kinectsdk and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/openkinect/v_EslQkZBQs/RxLi_mH--bsJ

Comment: I read this but my Kinect (actually both) is a Kinect for XBOX (not for Windows).